# Spotlight search still searchs when not selected

Tags: iphone

Why does my iPhone 5c save deleted emails and messages and displays them when spotlight search is turn on. There doesn't seem to be any way to delete them other than to reset and use backup to restore.

Answer (score 1):

Mail stays in Trash until you empty it.

Did you first empty the trash?

[image]

Select Edit, then Delete all.

Comment: Yes, and also deleted imessages but as soon as spotlight is turned on they reappear